# cannot import name 'pinv2' from 'scipy.linalg'

Tags: python, scipy

I want to import pinv2 from scipy.linalg:

```
from scipy.linalg import pinv2, inv
```

But I get an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'pinv2' from 'scipy.linalg' (C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py)
```

How  can I fix it or import pinv2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scipy.linalg.pinv2` was deprecated with version 1.7 and removed with version 1.9. The functionality has been subsumed by `scipy.linalg.pinv`.

See [changelogs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/search.html?q=pinv2).

Comment: thank you. I replaced pinv2 with pinv and its working.